# Math issue in python code. Formula issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code that I have written, please find traceback beneath final line.

```
kegsize = int(input('Please enter keg size. Litres: '))

costofkeg = int(input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: '))

abv = input('Please enter Alcohol by Volume. %: ')

gp = int(input('Please enter Gross Profit Percentage. %: '))

opt = print('These are the Portion Size options (imperial measurements), 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1')
portionsize = input('Please choose Portion Size: ')
if portionsize not in ['1/3' , '1/2' , '2/3' , '1']:
    print('Please enter a Portion Size from the list')
else:
    print('Thank you')

print ('Keg Size', kegsize, 'Litres')
print ('Cost of Keg', costofkeg, 'GBP')
print ('Alcohol by Volume', abv, '%')
print ('Gross profit percentage', gp, '%')


GrossSp = (costofkeg/(kegsize/portionsize*0.568)/(1-gp))*1.2)
```

I seem to have come across similar errors in the past, however can't find any code of mine where the same traceback is output. Please could someone teach me how to correct these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zico/Desktop/Papa, code.py", line 23, in <module>
    GrossSp = (costofkeg/(kegsize/portionsize*0.568)/(1-gp))*1.2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `portionsize` is a string...you need to convert it just like you did for others `int(input())` ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Could you please do it for me, if that's ok. Thank you!

Comment: Your issue is the line `portionsize = input('Please choose Portion Size: ')` That needs to be an int or a float

Comment: If i float this happens.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zico/Desktop/Papa, code.py", line 11, in <module>
    portionsize = float(input('Please choose Portion Size: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/3'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should make `portionsize` a number using `eval(input(...))`

Making it an `int` won't work,  since it can be 1/3, 1/2 or 2/3, which is not an `int`, so doing that will break your program.

Comment: If i float this happens. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Zico/Desktop/Papa, code.py", line 11, in <module> portionsize = float(input('Please choose Portion Size: ')) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/3'

Comment: @MotoStromm That is weird. Try `eval` instead.

Comment: "[Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)"

Answer (score 4):

`portionsize` is a str, not a numeric value. While you check that the value is in a list of allowed values, you do not finally convert it to a number.

You could either test for each option individually, or use a dict:

```
try:
    portionsize = {'1/3': 0.33, '1/2': 0.5, '2/3': 0.67, '1': 1}[portionsize]
except KeyError:
    print('Please enter a Portion Size from the list')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to divide by string (portionsize).